# Unable to call the method or change the value in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

So I defined a hashmap at first:

```
HashMap<String, PrivateChat> hash = new HashMap<String, PrivateChat>();
```

The PrivateChat is a class which has a String variant "ah" and a method "add".
But later when I try:

```
hash.get(name).add("hahaha"); // Add the value "hahaha" to ah variant.
```

It does nothing. In order to prove this is real, I tried:

```
System.out.println(hash.get(name).ah);
```

And the output is "". 

So the next time I tried modifying ah directly:

```
hash.get(name).ah += "hahaha";
```

And strange things happen to me, the ah still left unchanged. 
This is really a strange problem and I think no one has encountered before as I can't find any result on stackoverflow. 

 
Please help :D thanks 


Here is my current code of PrivateChat:

```
class PrivateChat {
    public JPanel field1;
    public JTextArea textArea1;
    public JTextField textField1;
    public JButton Send;
    public JLabel eac;

    public String ah = "";

    PrivateChat(final String name, final BufferedWriter bw) {
        eac.setText("You are talking with " + name);
        textArea1.setEditable(false);
        Send.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
                arr.add(name);
                arr.add(textField1.getText());
                String nts = Convert.ConvertToString(arr);
                try {
                    bw.write("/tell");
                    bw.flush();
                    bw.write(nts);
                    bw.flush(); // Gut.
                    add("\n[you] " + textField1.getText());
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    Send.setEnabled(false);
                    textField1.setEnabled(false);
                    textField1.setText("Failed: " + e1.toString());
                }
            }

        });
    }

    public void main(String name, BufferedWriter bw) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("PrivateChat");
        frame.setContentPane(new PrivateChat(name, bw).field1);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
        // frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void add(String buf) {
        ah += buf;
        textArea1.setText(ah);
        System.out.println("added: " + ah);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your PrivateChat class code? Looks like the problem may be there.

Comment: Please construct a minimal test-case.

Comment: The root cause of your issue seems to be in class `PrivateChat`

Comment: @Trinimon I have posted my code. Please help if you can

Comment: if any exception occurs then `ah` will not be changed.

Comment: @heo: Please add method `add` or show what you used to add the first item. I'd even retry it after the change. Reason why I'm asking for this is, that I think that the issue was inside of `add` .... so far it looks not too bad.

Comment: `PrivateChat` doesn't have an `add` method.

Comment: @immibis: yes and no: on the one hand OP mentioned `hash.get(name).add("hahaha");` - on the other hand it's not shown and OP wrote _"I deleted the add()"_. I'd like to see the implementation more clearly.

Comment: @immibis yes, because i deleted it just now.

Comment: @Prashant but there are no exceptions.

Comment: Note that your code is not thread-safe: you're accessing a swing component from a thread that is not the EDT, and this thread reads the value of ah that is modified by another thread without any synchronization, which will cause visibility issues (i.e. the thread might see obsolete values of ah)

Comment: @JBNizet I have changed the code many times and now that thread doesnt exist anymore.

Comment: @heo So, you're posting code that isn't the code you're actually executing. Enough of that. Post a **complete**, minimal test case reproducing the problem. Otherwise, we're all wasting our time.

Comment: Did you override equals and/or hashcode? Is the string 'ah' part of those?

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek I overrode nothing.

Comment: @heo: that doesn't reproduce the problem at all: thre code doesn't compile, it doesn't even have a proper main method, all the fields are uninitialized causing NPEs if we try to make it run, and nothing is added to the panel, making it impossible to click on the button. Voting to close.

Comment: @JBNizet It is too long if i have to display all the things.

Answer (score 3):

I've tested a simplified version of what you say it would be a problem to demonstrate that it should work. As other mentioned in the comments, you probably have more than this to show us and somewhere in your code something might be broken (exceptions thrown).
Also, I want to strongly recommand you change the `ah` variable visibility to private and make a accessor to modify its value, the way you implemented now it's not really safe.

```
public class PrivateChat {

    public String ah = "";

    @Override
    public String toString() {
       return "PrivateChat{" +
            "ah='" + ah + '\'' +
            '}';
    }
```

}

```
public class A {

    HashMap<String, PrivateChat> hash = new HashMap<String, PrivateChat>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        String myMapKey = "AAAA";
        a.hash.put(myMapKey, new PrivateChat());
        System.out.println("before modification:" + a.hash.get(myMapKey).ah);

        a.hash.get(myMapKey).ah += "blahblah";

        System.out.println("after modification:" + a.hash.get(myMapKey).ah);
    }
```

}

```
before modification:
after modification:blahblah
```

Comment: And there are no exceptions; I don't even need a try {. That's where I feel strange